# What is the difference between Triggers vs Simple Triggers in Google Cloud's logging facility, and why are they both showing up?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I created a google sheets file and added a `onEdit()` function.  In order to debug my code I was doing some logging by appending a row to a log sheet and I was getting some weird results where I was getting duplicate lines.  I changed my logged to use the `console.log()` function and it seems that the reason for the duplication is that these are showing up as 2 separate types.  One is `Trigger` and the other is `Simple Trigger`.  I don't understand why these are both showing up.  They have the same data, but the timestamp is slightly different.  My log function is as follows:

```
function stackTrace() {
    var err = new Error();
    return err.stack;
}

var logCount = 0;

function log(txt) {
  if (typeof(txt.stack) == "string") {
    // If txt has a member stack and it is a string, then this is most likey an Error object.
    console.log(
        `count: ${logCount++}\n` +
        `data: ${stackTrace().replace(/^Error\n\s+at stackTrace[^\n]+\n\s+at log[^\n]+(.*)/s, "Captured exception $1")}\n` +
        `stack: ${txt.stack}`
    );
  } else {
    console.log(
        `count: ${logCount++}\n` +
        `data: ${txt}\n` +
        `stack: ${stackTrace().replace(/^Error\n\s+at stackTrace[^\n]+\n\s+at log[^\n]+/, "Log")}`
    );
  }
}
```

The logged data is:

```
Project     Function    Type             Start Time                 Duration  Status
speedups    onEdit      Trigger          Jul 16, 2021, 1:21:08 AM   0.758 s   Completed
Cloud logs
Jul 16, 2021, 1:21:08 AM    Debug   count: 0
data: 99.0
stack: Log
    at onEdit (Code:12:7)
    at __GS_INTERNAL_top_function_call__.gs:1:8
...
Jul 16, 2021, 1:21:08 AM    Debug   count: 6
data: Captured exception 
    at inRange (Code:80:5)
    at onEdit (Code:15:38)
    at __GS_INTERNAL_top_function_call__.gs:1:8
stack: TypeError: Cannot set property 'undefined' of undefined
    at inRange (Code:75:12)
    at onEdit (Code:15:38)
    at __GS_INTERNAL_top_function_call__.gs:1:8
...
```

and

```
Project     Function    Type             Start Time                 Duration  Status
speedups    onEdit      Simple Trigger   Jul 16, 2021, 1:21:07 AM   0.703 s   Completed
Cloud logs
Jul 16, 2021, 1:21:08 AM    Debug   count: 0
data: 99.0
stack: Log
    at onEdit (Code:12:7)
    at __GS_INTERNAL_top_function_call__.gs:1:8
...
Jul 16, 2021, 1:21:08 AM    Debug   count: 6
data: Captured exception 
    at inRange (Code:80:5)
    at onEdit (Code:15:38)
    at __GS_INTERNAL_top_function_call__.gs:1:8
stack: TypeError: Cannot set property 'undefined' of undefined
    at inRange (Code:75:12)
    at onEdit (Code:15:38)
    at __GS_INTERNAL_top_function_call__.gs:1:8
...
```

As you can see, the only line that's different is the 2nd line, with the type being different, the timestamp is off by a second, and the duration also being slightly off.  Does this mean that the code is being executed twice?  All I have is a `onEdit` function.  I tried to reproduce this on a simpler file, but to no avail.

Can someone tell me what the two different types mean and perhaps why this could be occurring?

Comment: Check project triggers (https:// script.google. com/home/projects/***SCRIPT_ID***/triggers). Maybe a trigger is installed there?

Comment: @BorisBaublys, That was the cause.  Thx

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: @BorisBaublys, yup, already did that.  Just saw your answer just now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check project triggers (https://script.google.com/home/projects/***SCRIPT_ID***/triggers).
There is probably a trigger installed there.
[image]

Comment: Just to clarify, I didn't use your id in the url method. Instead, I went to https://script.google.com and clicked on the `My Triggers` menu item on the side panel. This got me to the same place without needing the id directly.

Comment: Because I didn't know your level, I was thinking how to write so that you get to the right place to remove the trigger :-) Chose this way.